# How do I deploy to private Maven repo from CloudBees?

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-3, cloudbees

I'd like to use CloudBees for my CI environment, but I'd also like to deploy my Maven artifacts to my existing private Nexus repository. In my current local Hudson setup, I utilize the username/password settings within the .m2/settings.xml file as follows:

```
...
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>my-repository</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
...
```

How/where can I configure these credentials on CloudBees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put these in your private webdav filestore: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Sharing+Files+with+Build+Executors

Then, just point Maven at this by passing the '-s' option, or clicked the "Advanced" section of your Maven build and add the path in the "Alternate settings file" field.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this step by step guide:

http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+under+an+external+Maven+repository