# How do I run install4j in CloudBees using Maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins, cloudbees, install4j

I have Maven build projects in a local Hudson instance that I would like to port to CloudBees. Install4j runs as an executable on the host system. In my experience, this includes an installer and registering the license key via the install4j UI.

How do I configure install4j so that I can run this build in the headless CloudBees environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to set this up, and it is very straight-forward.

### 1. Upload install4j to CloudBees

CloudBees runs on Linux, so extract and upload the Linux TAR.GZ version of install4j to your private repository.

HINT: via FTP => https://{username}@repository-{account}.forge.cloudbees.com/private

This directory is accessible from all build projects via the path: /private/{account}

### 2. Update Maven settings.xml

If you don't already have one, you'll need to create a settings.xml file in the same private repository.

Further reading on how to create a settings.xml: [How do I deploy to private Maven repo from CloudBees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383226/how-do-i-deploy-to-private-maven-repo-from-cloudbees)

You'll need to add the "install4j.home" and "install4j.licenseKey" properties to a profile in your settings.xml file according to the Sonatype Documentation*.

HINT: "install4j.home" is something like "/private/{account}/install4j5"

### 3. Update project pom.xml

Again, following the Sonatype Documentation*, update your project's pom.xml with the necessary build steps.

### * Sonatype Documentation

http://sonatype.github.com/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/

Comment: Jeff, thanks for this writeup. May I use this in our blog (with attribution)?